# How to calculate time complexitiy?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, big-o

I'm really having trouble calculating big O. I get the basics but when it gets to nested for loops and all that, my mind just blanks out. I was asked to write down the complexity of the following algorithm which I have no clue how to do. The input string contains only A,B,C and D

```
string solution(string &S) {
    int length = S.length();
    int i = 0;
    while(i < length - 1)
    {
        if ( (S[i] == 'A' && S[i+1] == 'B') || (S[i] == 'B' && S[i+1] == 'A'))
        {
            S = S.erase(i,2);
            i = 0;
            length = S.length();
        }
        
        if ( (S[i] == 'C' && S[i+1] == 'D') || (S[i] == 'D' && S[i+1] == 'C'))
        {
            S = S.erase(i,2);
            i = 0;
            length = S.length();
        }
        
        i++;
    }
    
    return S;
}
```

What would the big O of this algorithm be?

Comment: seems  like O(N) to me. you need to pass to all elements. Normal search is similar

Comment: @Nick: That's a lower bound, but big-O should be an upper bound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `O(n^2)`.

```
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDABABABABABABABABABABABAB
```

First n/2 characters are D
Last n/2 characters are AB

For each AB, (there are 1/4n such) - O(n)

- You are resetting i (iterating from start)
- shifting all successive elements to fill the gap created after erase.

Total:

```
O(n)*(O(n) + O(n)) = O(n^2)
```

Comment: I didnt clarify this but i will add it to the question, the input string only contains A,B,C and D.

Comment: @GeorgeKhanachat does not matter. Change X for D.

Comment: The `erase` is also O(n) each time it's called, but that is just as bad as the `i=0`. Technically you also need to prove that it's never worse than `n^2`. Your example is just a lower bound. E.g. `AAAABBBB` is also a subtle case, because erasing `AB` in the middle will form new AB pairs.

Comment: @TonyTannous: It doesn't move them to the end, but it does move the remaining characters. In this case, that would be O(n) characters which are moved forward by 2.

Comment: @MSalters shifting all successive elements to fill the gap created is indeed O(n) but its O(n) + O(n) to iterate from start. Not multiplied... meaning it will be O(n^2) at the end anyway. Am I wrong?

Comment: @TonyTannous: No, you're correct. In total, it's `(O(n) * (O(n)+O(n))`. And that simplifies to `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get hung up about the precise detail of how efficient an algorithm is.  Fundamentally though, all you're concerned about is whether the operation is:

- Constant time
- Proportional to the number of elements
- Proportional to the square of the number of elements

etc...

Look at this for guidance on how to estimate the Big-O for a compound operation:
https://hackernoon.com/big-o-for-beginners-622a64760e2

The big-O essentially defines the *worst-case complexity* of a method, with particular regard to effects that would be observed with very large `n`.  On the face of it you would consider how many times you repeat an operation, but you also need to consider if any embodied methods (e.g. string erase, string length) have complexity that's "constant time", "proportional to the number of elements", "proportional to the number of elements - squared" and so on.

So if your outer loop performs `n` scans but also invokes methods which also perform `n` scans on up to every item then you end up with O(n^2).

---

The main concern is the exponential dimension; you could have a very time-consuming linear-complexity operation, but also a very fast, say, power-of-4 element.  In such a case, it's considered to be O(n^4) ( *as opposed to O(20000n + n^4)* ) because *as n tends to infinity, all of the lesser exponent factors become insignificant*.  See here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties

---

So in your case, you have the following loops:

- Repetition of the scan (setting `i=0`) whose frequency is proportional to number of matches (worst case `n` for argument's sake - *even if it's a fraction, when `n` becomes infinite it remains significant*).  Although this is not supposedly the outer loop, it does fundamentally govern how many times the other scans are performed.
- String scan whose frequency is proportional to length (`n`), ***PLUS*** Embodied loop in the string erase - `n` in the worst case.  Note these operations are performed ***in isolation***, together governed by the frequency of the aforementioned repetition.  As stated elsewhere, `O(n)+O(n)` reduces to `O(n)` because we only care about exponent.

So in this case the complexity is **O(n^2)**

---

A separate consideration when assessing the performance of any algorithm regards how *cache friendly* it is; algorithms using hashmaps, linked lists etc are considered *prima-facie* to be more efficient, but in some cases a O(n^2) algorithm that operates within a cache line and doesn't invoke page faults nor cache flushes can execute a lot faster than a supposedly more efficient algorithm that has memory scattered all over the place.

Comment: It's `O(n^2)` regardless of string implementation.

Comment: I think with linked lists it would be O(n^3) as written because accessing linked lists by index is O(n). Of course you can get it back to O(n^2) by using iterators instead.

Comment: @TonyTannous Ah, just noticed the restart of the scan . That make it potentially *worse* than O(n^2)

Comment: @sepp2k the point about the string implementation concerns whether it has to shift the data through memory when deleting, as opposed to unlinking the deleted characters.

Comment: @Den-Jason I get that. I'm saying that `S.erase(i, 2)` is still an O(n) operation on linked lists (as is `S[i]`). Yes, the deletion itself will be instant, but you still need O(n) time to get to the `i`th node first. So if the string class were based on linked lists and the code were used as written (i.e. without replacing the indices with iterators), it'd be O(n^3). On a different note, I don't think C++ allows a linked-list-based implementation of `string` (pretty sure that random access on strings is guaranteed to be O(1)).

Comment: @sepp2k yes that appeared to change between c++98 and c++11.

Comment: The question is tagged C++, and the C++ Standard defines big-O complexities. `std::string` without question is not a linked list. Not in C++98, not in C++20. Its iterators are random access, O(1) access to the N'th element. Linked list have only forward or bidirectional iterators.

Comment: @MSalters if you look here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/ you will see that under C++98 the complexity is "unspecified".  I saw a video on this recently ("interfaces matter" IIRC) in which there was flexibility to allow an implementor to use non-contiguous data for std::string if they do desired.

Comment: @MSalters see here https://youtu.be/PG_sbSZL06U?t=1080

Comment: @Den-Jason: Ropes are "mostly contiguous". They're like `std::deque` in that regard.

Comment: @MSalters agreed.  Note the OP didn't specify `std::string` although it would be a fair assumption.  I think the main point that everyone's overlooking here though regards guiding the OP on how to work out complexity for himself, giving him resources if necessary.  I merely wanted to point out that the complexity of `erase` must be considered as opposed to assuming it doesn't matter.

Comment: It's correct that you have 3 loops, but they're not **nested loops**. Nested loops multiply, sequential loops add up. The "restart from i=0" happens if and only if there's an erase, so that's sequential.

Comment: edited again.  I owe you, Tony and sepp2k a beer :)

Answer (score -1):

I guess this would be O(n) because there is one loop thats going through the string.
The longer the string the more time it takes so i would say O(n)

Answer (score -1):

In big O notation, you give the answer for the worst case. Here the worst case will be that the string does not satisfy any if statements. Then time complexity here will be O(n) because there is only one loop.

Comment: Loop-through once is the *best case*.   The worst case here is if the conditional is taken every time.

Comment: @TonyTannous - no, because n delete operations are performed on the string.

Comment: @Den-Jason If the condition is taken every time then it will be less than O(n) because the length of the string will be reduced by 2 in every loop. Even considering the fact that we have to start from the beginning, it won't matter since the condition will always be true according to your case.

Comment: @Den-Jason n delete operations of 2 characters is still O(n)...

Comment: @TonyTannous Is `erase` (guaranteed to be) optimized for the case that the deletion happens at the very beginning? Otherwise each call to `erase` will have to shift each character in the string by two and doing that n/2 times is O(n^2).

Comment: @TonyTannous But we're not erasing them all in one go - we're deleting two at a time. We'd be calling `erase(0,2)` `n/2` times. If each call shifts every character by two, then that's a total running time of `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @NikunjDasKasat: The length may be lowered by 2 each time, but that makes the total complexity `N + (N-2) + (N-4) + ... ` . That is approximately `(N^2)/2`, and in big-O notation we ignore the constant `/2`.

Comment: @sepp2k: It doesn't even matter how exactly `erase` is optimized, because it can't be optimized for all cases. And the big-O bound is an upper bound for the worst input. The example `AAAABBBB` requires repeated erasure from the middle.

Comment: @sepp2k erase is O(n), but iterating from start is also O(n). O(n) + O(n) is still O(n). So I'd say total O(n^2).

Comment: @TonyTannous Yes, O(n^2) is what I said as well.