# Determining efficiency (Big O Notation) while using arrays in JavaScript

Tags: arrays, big-o

I am struggling to wrap my head around Big O notation and saw the following problem online. I must answer determining whether the following code is O(n), O(n²), O(logn), O(nlogn)

I have watched several videos but am still failing to understand Big O. Can someone please advise to the answer and their methodology for getting there?

```
function sortSmallestToLargest(entries):
    sorted_entries = {};

    while entries is not empty:
        smallest_entry = entries[0]

        foreach entry in entries:
            if (entry < smallest_entry):
                smallest_entry = entry

        sorted_entries.add(smallest_entry)
        entries.remove(smallest_entry)

    return sorted_entries
```

Comment: Maybe try my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64370621/how-to-calculate-time-complexitiy/64370834#64370834

Comment: Could you fix the identation? is `sorted_entries.add(smallest_entry)` inside the for loop, or perhaps the if? We can't tell.

Comment: I've submitted an edit according to how I think it should look - in which case the complexity is O(n^2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm iterates multiple time on 'entries' until it gets empty. first time in the inner loop it iterates n time (assuming entries length is n at start). second time in the inner loop it iterates n-1 time (because one item was removed in the previous iteration). So at the end we have this series of iterations:

n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 = n(n+1)/2 = O(n^2)